# Is it required to free (or delete) the arguments passed into main in C?

Tags: c++, c

If I have a main function like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is it required to deallocate argv? Can we deallocate argv? Should we deallocate argv?

Comment: Have you ever seen it done?

Comment: No. You only free() things which have been malloc() or calloc()d

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it required to deallocate argv?

No.

> Can we deallocate argv?

No. Though syntactically accepted, this would cause undefined behavior (runtime errors probably). The memory management of the `argv` array of pointers obliges the operating system (ABI bindings), which manages the process entry point (`main()`) and not the `main()` client definition.

> Should we deallocate argv?

No, you didn't allocate it, so you don't need to deallocate.

Comment: You gotta answer 'yes' at least once! I'd say, question number 2 is yes. I can deallocate argv, I only need to type 10 characters to do so.

Comment: @SergeyA That you don't get any errors is by chance. Its undefined behavior to call `delete argv`;`.

Comment: And I never claimed otherwise. However, when asked in a contrasting manner (can I/should I) i take the first to be the  question of physical possibility, not the correctness of the practice.

Comment: You see, 'can I grab the ball and run' asked about soccer game can have answers both yes and no. Same here.

Comment: @SergeyA More pleasant wording now?

Comment: Who am I to judge? But I like it better this way.

Comment: @SergeyA _"Who am I to judge?"_ As much as anyone else in this community. Pushing to give better answers and insist for better wording is a good action and much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Simple Concept: If you didn't allocate, you need not free too. : ))

Comment: ...except where functions like `strdup` have allocated memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would consider `strdup` an explicit allocation, much like `malloc` (which is what it does).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, but the answer is a bit dogmatic as advice for beginners; it pays to read the manual.

Comment: That's a bit over simplified.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not required. Yes, you can - in the same sense as 'can I jump from the Trump Tower straight to the ground?'. No, you should not.